# Error message when opening excel file using openXml in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I am trying to download the large excel file using open xml. I am able to download it. My excel file contains more than 100k records. When I double click on the file, I get below error message.

[image]

Below is my code.

```
public MemoryStream WriteExcelUsingOpenXML(IEnumerable<string> headers, IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> values, string worksheetName)
    {
      var stream = new MemoryStream();
      var headersArray = headers.ToArray();
      using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(stream, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
      {
        WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
        workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();

        WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

        Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());

        Sheet sheet = new Sheet() { Id = workbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart), SheetId = 1, Name = Constants.TimephaseWorksheet };

        sheets.Append(sheet);

        workbookPart.Workbook.Save();

        SheetData sheetData = worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new SheetData());

        // Constructing header
        Row row = new Row();
        foreach (var data in headersArray)
        {
          row.Append(ConstructCell(headersArray[0], CellValues.SharedString));
        }

        // Insert the header row to the Sheet Data
        sheetData.AppendChild(row);
        // Inserting each employee
        foreach (var valuesEnumeration in values)
        {
          row = new Row();
          var flattend = valuesEnumeration.ToArray();
          row.Append(
              ConstructCell(flattend[0], CellValues.Number),
              ConstructCell(flattend[1], CellValues.SharedString),
              ConstructCell(flattend[2], CellValues.SharedString),
              ConstructCell(flattend[3], CellValues.Number),
              ConstructCell(flattend[4], CellValues.SharedString));

          sheetData.AppendChild(row);
        }

        worksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();
      }

      return stream;
    }

    private Cell ConstructCell(string value, CellValues dataType)
    {
      return new Cell()
      {
        CellValue = new CellValue(value),
        DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(dataType)
      };
    }
```

Below is the sample data of excel file.

[image]

How to fix the error?

Comment: Debug it and see what exception is raised

Comment: Hi, No exception. I am able to download it. Whenever i double click to open it, below error message coming. If i click on yes i am able to see excel with required data